# Search by Author: domain\user or email or Name and Surname?

Tags: search, claims-based-auth, search-results, windows-authentication

I have a problem with search "by Author" in sharepoint 2010.

I have 2 farms, one with Windows Auth and one with Claim Based... I have an application that has to work in the same way in each installation...

In windows auth: Author: Name Surname
In claim based: Author: name.surname@domain.xxx

There is a way to make search work in the same way in the two farms?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do your claims based users have their name filled in properly in their use profiles? Search should be able to search by full name, that is when the author field in the document library lists a full name, instead of the login (which is used when no name is available).

Comment: Yes, name is filled but works ONLY if I search by email..

Comment: Strange, I would know then, sorry. Normally a person field would be filled with something like "45#;Firstname Surname", where search would use the latter part. But I'm no expert on this unfortunately.